# Matching repeating patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently trying to match and capture text in the following input:

```
field: one two three field: "moo cow" field: +this
```

I can match the `field:` with `[a-z]*\:` however I can't seem to match the rest of the content so far my attempts have only resulted in capturing everything which is not what I want to do.

Comment: What is it you wnt to capture exactly? everything after, but not including the `field:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that it is always going to be literally `field:` there is absolutely no need for a regular expression:

```
var delimiters = new String[] {"field:"};
string[] values = input.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

However, from your regex I assume that the name `field` can vary, as long as it's in front of a colon. You could try to capture a word followed by `:` and then everything up to the next of those words (using a lookahead).

```
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"([a-z]+):((?:(?![a-z]+:).)*)"))
{
    string fieldName = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string value = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

An explanation of the regular expression:

```
(     # opens a capturing group; the content can later be accessed with Groups[1]
[a-z] # lower-case letter
+     # one or more of them
)     # end of capturing group
:     # a literal colon
(     # opens a capturing group; the content can later be accessed with Groups[2]
(?:   # opens a non-capturing group; just a necessary subpattern which we do not
      # need later any more
(?!   # negative lookahead; this will NOT match if the pattern inside matches
[a-z]+:
      # a word followed by a colon; just the same as we used at the beginning of
      # the regex
)     # end of negative lookahead (not that this does not consume any characters;
      # it LOOKS ahead)
.     # any character (except for line breaks)
)     # end of non-capturing group
*     # 0 or more of those
)     # end of capturing group
```

So first we match `anylowercaseword:`. And then we match one more character at a time, for each one checking that this character is not the start of `anotherlowercaseword:`. With the capturing groups we can then later separately find the field's name and the field's value.

Comment: As well as the answer may work for him, I think newcomers to regex will have a hard time trying to understand this...

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester You are probably right, but I usually get scolded by more experienced users for providing simplified answers :D.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Added some rather extensive explanation ;)

Comment: Looks good! Even I understood it. Did you use some tool to write that up and format it? I see it took you just 5 minutes, or are you just a fast typer?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I guess I'm just a fast typer then ;). I did that all by hand.

Comment: @m.buettner this is an amazing answer, not simply because of the solution but in that its described in a way that can be understood easily. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can actually match literal strings in regexes. If your pattern is like this:

```
field\:
```

You will match "field:" literally, and nothing else.